# com.mysql.jdbc.Driver not found in Runnable jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc, jar

I have implemented simple **Swing application which creates database** and added mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar to my projects build path. it works fine when I run in Eclipse as a project. But I exported this project to runnable jar file it doesnt work.

I write some code to print exceptions to file. It gives this line :
**java.lang.ClassNotFoundException : com.mysql.jdbc.Driver**

I already added required jars to my project. I cant understand why it doesnt work ?

Comment: Please share the code to solve your issue properly. Also try to extract your jar file and see whether Driver class exist in that jar package.

Comment: Java won't locate Jar files that are inside other Jar files.  You need to zip all the files together and have the user unzip them so they're separate so they can be found.

Comment: We're going to need your runnable jar build settings for Eclipse. This is an Eclipse-related issue as well, so I will add that tag.

Comment: I use "Extract required libraries into generated JAR" option to create jar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your JAR is not having the required libraries.

You need to export the application using the option `Package required libraries into generated JAR`.

Comment: Thanks bro, I add connector as a referenced lib and export this project with "Package required libraries into generated JAR" option. It works :)